# How to recursively call an asynchronous function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, recursion

I've defined this function:

```
// retrieves zip of package manifest supplied

var retrieveZip = function(metadataClient, args, callback) {
  metadataClient.retrieve(args, function(err, result) {
    metadataClient.checkRetrieveStatus({id: result.result.id, includeZip: 'true'}, function(err, result) {
      if(result.result.done) {
        return callback(result);
      }
      // else check again!(how??)
    });
  });
}

retrieveZip(metadataClient, args, function(result) {
      console.log(result);
});
```

The idea is that the client will attempt to retrieve a zip file based on the metadata supplied in args. The API documentation (Salesforce SOAP API) requires the id supplied in the result of the retrieve method to be passed into a check status function.

However the problem is this:

1. On the first check, if the result is 'done' then just return to the callback the result object from `checkRetreiveStatus` (contains the result)
2. BUT if the result isn't done, I need to call `checkRetrieveStatus` again... from inside `checkRetrieveStatus`
3. The naive approach would be to pass the parameters from the original `checkRetrieveStatus` call into a new instance of `checkRetrieveStatus` but obviously it's impossible to know how many times this would be invoked.

It sounds like I need a recursive solution to this? Would using a while-loop would introduce problems with asynchronous calls?

Comment: call a function and pass callback to it. Call `callback` on success and Inside callback, call self (next iteration).

Comment: It's worth noting that recursion is meant to be theoretically infinite. You can pass a counter for recursive functions, but the idea is that you don't need to know the number of cals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, it sounds like you just want to call `checkRetrieveStatus` until it's done,  *not* `retrieve` *and* `checkRetrieveStatus`. Is that correct?

If so, the thing to do is to extract the status check out into your own function that can recursively call itself, like this:

```
var checkStatus = function(metadataClient, id, callback) {
    metadataClient.checkRetrieveStatus({ id: id, includeZip: 'true' }, function(err, result) {
        if (result.result.done) {
            callback(result); 
        } else {
            checkStatus(metadataClient, id, callback);
        }
    });
};

var retrieveZip = function(metadataClient, args, callback) {
  metadataClient.retrieve(args, function(err, result) {
      checkStatus(metadataClient, result.result.id, callback);
  });
}

retrieveZip(metadataClient, args, function(result) {
      console.log(result);
});
```

And if you're worried about hogging system resources while it repeatedly polls the result, you can include a delay between checks:

```
var checkStatus = function(metadataClient, id, callback) {
    metadataClient.checkRetrieveStatus({ id: id, includeZip: 'true' }, function(err, result) {
        if (result.result.done) {
            callback(result); 
        } else {
            setTimeout(function () {
                checkStatus(metadataClient, id, callback);
            }, 100);
        }
    });
};

var retrieveZip = function(metadataClient, args, callback) {
  metadataClient.retrieve(args, function(err, result) {
      checkStatus(metadataClient, result.result.id, callback);
  });
}

retrieveZip(metadataClient, args, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: How did I miss that?!

Comment: This is great, thanks for the help. Never occurred to me to recursively call the function that invokes checkRetrieveStatus.

Answer (score 0):

Better to split the function so you do not have to re-enter the top.something like this (did not try to run this, so just get the idea)

```
// retrieves zip of package manifest supplied

var retrieveZip = function(metadataClient, args, callback) {
  metadataClient.retrieve(args, function(err, result) {
    doCheck(result,function(res){
       callback(res)
    })

  });
}


function doCheck(result,cb){
 metadataClient.checkRetrieveStatus({id: result.id, includeZip: 'true'}, function(err, innerResult) {
     if(result.result.done) {
            return cb(result);
      }else{
    doCheck( innerResult ,cb)
    }
  });
}

retrieveZip(metadataClient, args, function(result) {
      console.log(result);
});
```